# Sending Custom Data from Custom Select field in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

i have created a custom select field into my datatable

```
html = '<div class="col-md-3"><select id="filterleads" class="filterleads form-control">';
        html += '<option value="all">All Leads</option>';
        html += '<option value="processed">Processed Leads</option>';
        html += '<option value="unprocessed">Unprocessed Leads</option>';
        html += '</select></div>';

         $("div.toolbar").html(html);
```

which looks like this
[image]

now when the select changes i want it to send its value with the datatable ajax so i can filter records according to that

this is how im doing this

```
var table = $('#allleadstable').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 50,
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
            "sScrollXInner": "100%",
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "ajax": {
                url:"/leads",
                data: {
                    "leadfilter": ($("#filterleads").val() ? $("#filterleads").val() : 'all')
                        }
            },
            "scrollX":true,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            //"sDom": '<"top"flip>rt<"bottom"flip><"clear">',
            "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
            columnDefs: [
                { width: 60, targets: 0 },
                { width: 50, targets: 1 },
                { width: 50, targets: 2 },
                { width: 150, targets: 3 },
                { width: 150, targets: 4 },
                { width: 100, targets: 5 },
                //{ width: 100, targets: 7 },
                { width: 100, targets: 6 }
            ]
        });

        $(document).on("change", "#filterleads", function(event) {
            table.ajax.reload();
        });
```

The problem is that it doesn't find `$("#filterleads")` and always send the value 'all' even when i change the select

How do I send its value everytime I change select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you only read the value of your select when the page loads, and it's `all` by default. You need to change your code so that it reads the value of the select when it makes the request. To do this provide a function to the `data` property:

```
"ajax": {
    url: "/leads",
    data: function(data) {
        data.leadfilter = $("#filterleads").val()
    }
},
```

Note that I removed the ternary as it's not needed. The `select` will always have a value.

For more information see the [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) entry in the DataTables documentation.

Comment: it is showing an error custom.js:355 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: thanks it worked but there was one more error, removed ")" after data{}

Comment: and without adding ternary it doesnt send its value with ajax the first time it loads

Comment: Ah, I guess you're calling the DataTable before the DOM is ready, or the select is loaded dynamically?

Comment: Ok, you need the ternary in that case then :)

Answer (score 0):

For one dynamic field and 2 static its also may looks like:

```
ajax: {
    url: '/action.php',
    data: {
        controller: 'someController',  
        action: 'someAction',
        leadfilter: () => $('#filterleads').val()
    }
},
```